# how to fix expected identifier before ';' token error

Tags: c

ı am beginner programmer. I want to create a small database and choose from them for some requirements. It contains lots of definition of something so it looks long but it is not. I think like there are objects and we add thins to it and then compare the properties. Is C suitable for this task.

```
#include<stdio.h>

typedef struct{
    char isim;
    int adet;
    int odunc_alinma_sayisi;
    int sayfa;
    char yazar;
}kitap_ozellikleri;

kitap_ozellikleri a;
kitap_ozellikleri c;
kitap_ozellikleri y;
kitap_ozellikleri e;
kitap_ozellikleri t;
kitap_ozellikleri k;

/*int range(int maks){
    if(maks==1) {
        return 1;
    }
    int sayilar[maks];
    sayilar[maks-1] = maks;
    sayilar[maks-2] = range(maks-1); 
    return sayilar[];
}
*/
    void ozellik_tanimla(){
        a.adet = 50;
        a.isim = 'a';
        a.odunc_alinma_sayisi = 30;
        a.sayfa = 280;
        a.yazar = 'e';

        c.adet = 82;
        c.isim = 'c';
        c.odunc_alinma_sayisi = 88;
        c.sayfa = 150;
        c.yazar = 'g';

        y.adet = 99;
        y.isim = 'y';
        y.odunc_alinma_sayisi = 123;
        y.sayfa = 119;
        y.yazar = 'k';

        e.adet = 53;
        e.isim = 'e';
        e.odunc_alinma_sayisi = 33;
        e.sayfa = 268;
        e.yazar = 'r';

        t.adet = 24;
        t.isim = 't';
        t.odunc_alinma_sayisi = 42;
        t.sayfa = 159;
        t.yazar = 'o';

        k.adet = 55;
        k.isim = 'k';
        k.odunc_alinma_sayisi = 110;
        k.sayfa = 296;
        k.yazar = 'o';
    }


    int main(){
        ozellik_tanimla();  
        char liste[6] = {'a','c','y','e','t','k'};
        char yazar_liste[6] = {'e','g','k','r','o','o'};
        int n = 0;
        for(n=0;n<6;n++){
            int z = 0;
            for(z=0;z<6;z++){
                if(yazar_liste[n]==yazar_liste[z]){
                    kitap_ozellikleri gecici1 = yazar_liste[n]-> ;
                    kitap_ozellikleri gecici2 =  yazar_liste[z]->;
                    gecici1.sayfa += gecici2.sayfa;
                }
            }
        }

return 0;
    }
```

I want to learn what is this error and why it occurs?

Comment: `yazar_liste[n]-> ;` is not valid syntax, the arrow needs something after it. Or the arrow needs to be removed, it doesn't make sense here. But then I don't understand what your code is trying to do there at all. Start much smaller, make a simpler bit of code with a lot less data and make that work.

Comment: `gecici1 = yazar_liste[n]->;` The variable `gecici1` is a structure, and `yazar_liste[n]` is a `char`. The `->` after `yazar_list[n]` is not valid, since `yazar_list[n]` is not a struct. Beyond that, it's not clear what you're trying to do on that line.

Comment: I assumed that arrays is a kind of pointer and if I write sth like that ı could reach the 'kitap_ozellikleri a' struct. I learned ı couldnt but how can ı access to properties of 'a' .

Comment: Aside: the `struct` initialisation can be simpler with `kitap_ozellikleri a = { 'a', 50, 30, 280, 'e' };` and so on, then the function `ozellik_tanimla()` can be removed.

Comment: @Weather Vane, Thanks ı will consider this.

Comment: Arrays are ***not*** pointers, though in most contexts they are *converted to* pointers when evaluated.  But even if they were, the `->` is specific to accessing *members* of structures through pointers *to structures*.  To get an array element, you can just use the array indexing operator as you already do: `yazar_liste[n]`.

Comment: `sayfa` translates to "page" in English. Is that the number of pages in a book? Are you trying to find the total number of pages written by each author?

Comment: By the way: You should get used to adopt English only identifiers. While in given case, it's rather matter of syntax and thus not that relevant, you'll certainly have to share code with other people not aware of your mother tongue in the future, too – and be it only here on SO. However, not understanding the intention of a variable or function makes it much harder, if not impossible, to help you...

Comment: @Aconcagua Try inputting the codebase into Google Translate. It's in Turkish.

Comment: I know but ı dont know english well

Comment: @ user3386109 yes ı m trying to find total number of pages written by author

Comment: @JL2210 And you'd want to do that on every bit of piece of code you receive from some colleague?

Comment: @Aconcagua Not really, but for now it works.

Comment: @OğuzhanyusufAslanalp Don't see it as criticism, see it as recommendation. It will help you if you need to cooperate with others, and for writing code, you only need a very basic English level, at least if not considering good commentation...

Comment: I 'd want to learn the cause of this error and try to learn the C language.

Comment: Well, cause of error is the accessor `->`. It is there to access a member of some struct. `x->y` actually is just syntactic sugar, short hand for `(*x).y`. Similarly, the index operator is just syntactic sugar as well, `x[y]` is short for `*(x + y)`.

Comment: The definition `kitap_ozellikleri gecici1` is local to that `if` code block, and goes out of scope before you have even used it for anything. Suppose you define `kitap_ozellikleri gecici1;` further out - at the scope where you want to use what you set its members to, then the error line can be `gecici1.ism = yazar_liste[n];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.

I think I can discern your intent from the comments on the question and the other answer, and I believe what you want for your core loop is something more like this:

```
kitap_ozellikleri gecici1;
kitap_ozellikleri liste[6] = {a, c, y, e, t, k};  // no 'quotes'
char yazar_liste[6] = {'e', 'g', 'k', 'r', 'o', 'o'};
for(n=0; n<6; n++) {
    for(z=0; z<6; z++) {
        if(yazar_liste[n] == liste[z].yazar){
            gecici1.sayfa += liste[z].sayfa;
        }
    }
}
```

Do you see why I changed `liste` to a `kitap_ozellikleri[]` and removed the `''` quotes around the members of that array?

This compiles (after adding overhead like `int n, z;`), but as-written, this counts the total number of pages written by all the authors listed in `yazar_liste[]`.  But, it also double-counts the author "o", because that author is listed twice in `yazar_liste[]`.

Here is a full version, incorporating suggestions from various comments, which *prints out* counts per author:

**code**

```
#include<stdio.h>

typedef struct{
    char isim;
    int adet;
    int odunc_alinma_sayisi;
    int sayfa;
    char yazar;
}kitap_ozellikleri;

kitap_ozellikleri a = { 'a', 50, 30,  280, 'e' };
kitap_ozellikleri c = { 'c', 82, 88,  150, 'g' };
kitap_ozellikleri y = { 'y', 99, 123, 119, 'k' };
kitap_ozellikleri e = { 'e', 53, 33,  268, 'r' };
kitap_ozellikleri t = { 't', 24, 42,  159, 'o' };
kitap_ozellikleri k = { 'k', 55, 110, 296, 'o' };

int main(){
    int n, z, tot;

    kitap_ozellikleri liste[6] = {a, c, y, e, t, k};  // no 'quotes'
    char yazar_liste[6] = {'e', 'g', 'k', 'r', 'o'};
    for(n=0; n<5; n++) {
        tot = 0;
        for(z=0; z<6; z++) {
            if(yazar_liste[n] == liste[z].yazar){
                tot += liste[z].sayfa;
            }
        }
        printf("total pages for sayfa %c is : %d\n", yazar_liste[n], tot);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**output**

```
total pages for sayfa e is : 280
total pages for sayfa g is : 150
total pages for sayfa k is : 119
total pages for sayfa r is : 268
total pages for sayfa o is : 455
```

To instead *store* per-author counts (e.g., for use later on in the program), you would need to introduce a way of tracking several counters.  I will leave that as an exercise for you; but of course if you have questions after trying it, feel free to post another, separate SO question, detailing what you've tried, your results, and your expected results.

Comment: Nice answer, I suggest initialisation with `kitap_ozellikleri gecici1 = { 0 };` so that `gecici1.sayfa` can accumulate the pages.

Comment: Yes ı see, you create a list of struct

Comment: @ Weather Vane why do you initialize it?

Comment: For the same reason that the answer initialises `tot = 0;` Local variables are not automatically initialised, and I was referring to the first version with `gecici1.sayfa += liste[z].sayfa;` where `gecici1.sayfa` was never set to `0`.

Comment: @WeatherVane : agreed, 100%;  I would have added the initialization of `gecici1`, but I decided to incorporate your other suggestion about printing out the per-author totals along the way, and edited my answer to distinguish *print-as-you-go* from *store-for-later-use*;  you provided very useful comments!

Comment: Thanks everyone for their answers:)

Comment: @OğuzhanyusufAslanalp : our pleasure; we are here to help the global community of developers;  please consider 'accepting' one of the answers, to indicate that it solved your problem and/or was particularly helpful to your understanding of the problem; thanks

Comment: @OğuzhanyusufAslanalp as a welcome new contributor you might benefit by reading the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and other [help topics](https://stackoverflow.com/help), also the [Stackoverflow FAQ coding questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c?sort=frequent&pageSize=15).

Answer (score 1):

These two lines are invalid:

```
kitap_ozellikleri gecici1 = yazar_liste[n]-> ;
kitap_ozellikleri gecici2 =  yazar_liste[z]->;
```

Just remove the `->`s. These are invalid because `yazar_liste` is not a pointer to a structure.

If you want this to compile (it may or may not work), change your `main` function to be like this:

```
int main(){
    ozellik_tanimla();  
    char liste[6] = {'a','c','y','e','t','k'};
    char yazar_liste[6] = {'e','g','k','r','o','o'};
    int n = 0;
    for(n=0;n<6;n++){
        int z = 0;
        for(z=0;z<6;z++){
            if(yazar_liste[n]==yazar_liste[z]){
                kitap_ozellikleri gecici1 = { .yazar = yazar_liste[n] };
                kitap_ozellikleri gecici2 = { .yazar = yazar_liste[z] };
                gecici1.sayfa += gecici2.sayfa;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: @P__J__ See update. I'm not sure what this does, so I can't be sure if it works, but it compiles now.

Comment: @OğuzhanyusufAslanalp What's "sth"?

Comment: I dont know english well but my teachers always use 'sth' instead of something

Comment: @OğuzhanyusufAslanalp Oh. Well, see my updated answer. You need to remove those because the `yazar_liste` is not a pointer to a structure.

Comment: My aim is to find the books which has the same writer. "yazar" means writer and ı give letters to writers.

Comment: @OğuzhanyusufAslanalp, for future information, "sth" is not used as an abbreviation for "something" by native English speakers.

Comment: @JohnBollinger See https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19841/what-is-meant-by-sth. Also see the second comment on the accepted answer.

Comment: Absolutely true, @JL2210, as I can confidently assert as a native and longtime English speaker and prolific reader and writer.  Use *in dictionaries*, to the extent that it occurs, is not the same as use by native speakers, and especially not the same as use in ordinary writing.

Comment: This code makes much more sense when I plug it into Google Translate.

Comment: :) I was proficiency student this year. I learnt a lot about engliah but I realised that ı dont know anything.